# Range of Confidence Interval falls outside what is possible

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

I am collecting data to look at some correlations and noticed something that I never thought about in-depth during the earlier stage when I had little observations to work with.

Between two of my variables early on I found a significant correlation of around $r=-0.85$ with a small sample size of $N=23$. I know that outliers will skew the point estimate with this little data even if it is deemed to be significant through the $p < 0.05$ approach.

I found that the standard error of correlation can be calculated through $\sqrt \frac{1-r^2}{N-2}$ which in this specific case leads to a standard error of around 0.115.

My question comes when I calculate confidence intervals for r. If I were to create a 95% confidence interval I would have $(-0.85-1.96 \cdot 0.115, -0.85+1.96 \cdot 0.115)$ which evaluates to  $(-1.0754, -0.6246)$. As this is a correlation, the range of $r$ can only fall between -1 and 1 so the $-1.0754$ lower range of that 95% confidence interval is not attainable.

In such a case, would the 95% confidence interval just cut off at -1 and become $(-1, -0.6246)$?

Comment: How are you calculating the confidence interval? If you are using the actual distribution function of $r$ then it shouldn't be possible to step outside of $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Your confidence interval calculations involving $1.96$ seem to presuppose a Gaussian distribution.  Clearly this is not the case for $r$

Comment: You are both absolutely right. Thank you, I mistakenly have assumed a normal distribution when that's not what should be used for correlation statistics. After an internet search I learned of the proper way to construct a confidence interval for this scenario. Thank you both very much.